# Proper way to get queryParams with Angular2 RC6

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Please only provide answers current for RC6 and above.

I recently attempted to upgrade from RC1 to RC6 and found RouteSegment is gone.  After a lot of digging, I've found ActivatedRoute, however it appears to be WAY over complicated for pulling out a raw value from the url.

Is the new correct way to read a static query value the following?

```
const id : Observable<number> = this.route.queryParams.map(p => p.id);
```

If so, can some please explain why I need a map and an observable just to pull the value 6 out of the URL's query string?

Can someone please explain what new cool feature I have at my disposal to warrant this much increase in code complexity?

If I'm missing something obvious, please point me in the right direction.  I'd prefer to stick to a simple URL query system like: let id = params.id;

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-home-component',
    template: `
                <h1>
                    Home Component!
                </h1>
                <hr>
                {{param}}
              `,
    styles: []
 })

export class HomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private subscription: Subscription;

    param: string;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
         this.subscription = route.queryParams.subscribe(
             (queryParam: any) => this.param = queryParam['paramName']
         );
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

You can also use snapshot (less code)
ex: `let foo = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['foo'];`
if your component is not reusable. Otherwise this snapshot will be only created once and will not change when you re-navigate to the same component with different param (meaning changing just a parameter in current url).

Here's the example:

Let's say you're at `mydomain/mycomponent?id=1`

You can use a subscription to Observable queryParams or snapshot to get the 'id' parameter value. Results will be the same.

Now navigate to `mydomain/mycomponent?id=2` and using subscription you will get '2' as a value, but using snapshot it will still be '1'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but do I really need a subscription, more stateful information and the possibility for dangling handles just to pull a static value out of the URL query?  Do you know anything about snapshot?  I just found that and am reading.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html

Comment: You can use shapshot if your component is not reusable. Otherwise this snapshot will be created only once and will not change during the component's life time.

Comment: Do you have any docs to explain a situation where a component can change via URL variables?

Comment: Let's say you're now at http://mydomain/mycomponent?id=1
You can use a subscription to Observable queryParams or shapshot to get the 'id' parameter value. They will be the same.
Now navigate to http://mydomain/mycomponent?id=2 and using subscription you will get '2' as a value, but using shapshot it will still be 1.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll have to ponder on that.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Can you post an example for using snapshot in your answer so the next person that sees this will have info on both ways to handle it?  Thanks again.

Comment: @LukeDupin, updated:
let foo = this.route.snapshot.queryParams['foo'];