# Angular AcitivatedRoute not extracting queryParams correctly

Tags: angular, routes

I Need to extract a queryParam of a given URL and I tried to do with the ActivatedRoute object like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let code: string;
    //option 1 code = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('code');
    //option 2 this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => code = queryParams.get('code'));
    console.log(code);

  }
```

Both Methods have the same result, they extract a Code that's not the same as in the given URL.

Does anyone know what fault I made? Thank you very much!

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Your output looks like the decoded version of your url and seems to be ok. Pls use text instead of images.

Comment: you need to subscribe to the queryparams, snapshot doesn't update Check out [Proper way to get queryParams with Angular2 RC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340193/proper-way-to-get-queryparams-with-angular2-rc6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to get queryParams with Angular2 RC6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340193/proper-way-to-get-queryparams-with-angular2-rc6)

Comment: it's the same but it's encoded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the same but encoded if you want the same value you have to decode it

```
let code: string;
//option 1 code = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('code');
//option 2 this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(queryParams => code = queryParams.get('code'));
console.log(decodeURI(code)); // decode it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you have imported ActivatedRoute from "@angular/router" and also it is necessary to inject this ActivatedRoute inside constructor as Dependency injection.

Then we can use ActivatedRoute to get the queryparam from the url.

Comment: if that was the case, it wouldn't compile or even get any params,

Comment: Yes,You are right. Then may be for security reasons they might have encoded the url